# Docker run -p 3000-3000 not working instead I have to use port 32779

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I cannot reach localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000 even though my node app is running in docker and listening on port 3000. instead I have to use locahost:32779

Any idea why?

**Docker file**

```
...
EXPOSE 3000
...
```

**app.js**

```
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**CMD**

```
docker run -p 3000-3000 test
 --> Example app listening on port 3000!
```

**browser**

```
localhost -> This site can’t be reached
```

**CMD**

```
docker ps -a

95d2ce8        test                "/bin/sh -c 'node ap…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                     0.0.0.0:32779->3000/tcp   distracted_thompson
```

Comment: Typo…? `3000:3000`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind just a one port, you should to write `-p 3000:3000`:

```
$ docker run -p 3000:3000 test
```